# How to extract influential features from ANN?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am working on ANN with 12[layer1 or ip] +6[Hidden layer-reLU]+6[Hidden layer-reLU]+1[output layer-sigmoid] using keras and want to know which input feature  most influences the output.

Answer (score 0):

How to measure importance of inputs is clearly discussed in the below link:

You can always remove different factors from the input, then train and test the neural network. Removing the most significant features will result in the biggest decline in classification accuracy. Of course, this method is not precise because removing inputs will change the NN architecture, and thus its properties.

[Link to extract influential features](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/importance.html)